# Android force close on using Swipe to Dismiss Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am using the swipe-to-dismiss library but the app crashes after after the list item is swiped away. I am using the following code :

```
todolist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.todo_items);
        SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
                new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                        todolist,
                        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
        todolist.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        todolist.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
```

The app gives a UnsupportedoperationException on this line :

```
com.example.todolist.ToDoListActivity$1.onDismiss(ToDoListActivity.java:81)
```

How do I fix this ? I am referring to this code sample :

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/MainActivity.java

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your ArrayAdapter by either calling one of the constructors that takes an object array instead of a List, or you passed it an immutable List.

Try instead calling one of the ArrayAdapter constructors that takes a List and be sure to pass it one that is mutable.  This will allow you perform the remove operation.

Internally, the ArrayAdapter constructors that take object array will create a List out of your object array by calling Arrays.asList(T... array) on it, but the List Arrays.asList returns is immutable.

As an example, consider the following data:

```
String[] FRUIT = {"Apple", "Banana", "Pear"};
```

Both of the following will create adapters that will throw the UnsupportedOperationException:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FRUIT);

new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arrays.asList(FRUIT));
```

Whereas this one will allow you to modify the adapter's list:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(FRUIT)));
```